# msgbus - finding the correct property to track

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble understanding msgbus.
What I would like is to implement a callback every time a compositor node is selected and I am getting some behavior from msgbus that I don't quite understand.

Take the following code (adapted from what I have found around):

```
import bpy
        
def msgbus_callback(*arg):
    print("-->", bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active)

def subscribe_to_obj(): 
             
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=(bpy.types.Nodes, 'active'),
        owner=bpy,
        args=('something, if you need',),
        notify=msgbus_callback
        )
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    subscribe_to_obj()
```

This will not print anything if you select a node in the composite tree.
However, if you change the active node from a python console.

`bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.nodes["Composite"]`

then the shell outputs what's expected :

`--> <bpy_struct, CompositorNodeComposite("Composite") at 0x13c549418>`

It will also work if you create (from the UI) any new node in the compositor tree.

Another example:

This will work fine if you change the color of any CompositorNodeOutputFile from the UI or the python console.

```
def subscribe_to_obj(): 
             
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=(bpy.types.CompositorNodeOutputFile, "color"),
        owner=bpy,
        args=('something, if you need',),
        notify=msgbus_callback
        )
```

according to the [CompositorNodeOutputFile](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CompositorNodeOutputFile.html) doc  the color property is inherited from the [Node](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html#bpy.types.Node.color) but then if I try this

```
def subscribe_to_obj(): 
             
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
        key=(bpy.types.Node, "color"),
        owner=bpy,
        args=('something, if you need',),
        notify=msgbus_callback
        )
```

Nothing is printed when changing the color of a compositor node from the UI or from the python console.

```
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active.color = (1, 0.5, 1)
```

So it looks like there is something I don't quite understand, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: After some more reading it looks like a limitation on the msgbus functionality : https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/message-bus/